# Heinlein, "Everything not compulsory was forbidden," in "Coventry?"

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, quotes

There is a satirical phrase, "Everything not forbidden is compulsory," which seems to have been a part of popular culture (in varied form) in the English-speaking world in the early 20th century. It was later used by Murray Gell-Mann as a tongue-in-cheek way of formulating a [fundamental principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle) of quantum mechanics. In the physics context, it's referred to as the "totalitarian principle." I ran across a [comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Everything_which_is_not_forbidden_is_allowed#Heinlein) on a WP talk page saying that Heinlein uses this phrase in the 1940 story "Coventry." Can anyone help me track down where in the story it occurs? It's a pretty long story. What I have handy is the 1967 Berkley mass-market paperback edition of The Past Through Tomorrow, but if anyone can point me to the general location within the story, I should be able to find it.

Comment: I believe the phrase originates with [The Once and Future King](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/o/the-once-and-future-king/summary-and-analysis-the-sword-and-the-stone/chapter-13) by T H White.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Actually that turns out to be wrong. I've done some edits to the WP article, which used to claim that. For a careful historical discussion, see thepaper by Kragh referenced in the WP article. White didn't publish the phrase in print util 1958.

Comment: Huh.  I thought *Once and Future King* was much older than that.  My mistake.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The story existed in a series of different versions. The phrase didn't appear until the 1958 version. The Kragh paper goes into all this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It’s about a quarter of the way through:

> The state was thought of as a single organism with a single head, a
>   single brain, and a single purpose. Anything not compulsory was
>   forbidden.

Comment: For anyone else trying to locate it, it's about two pages after the end of the courtroom scene, inserted as an authorial explanation during a dialog between David MacKinnon and Fader Magee.

Comment: @BenCrowell It's pretty easy to find it here, just search for "compulsory": https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v25n05_1940-07_dtsg0318